# sapui5 PlanningCalendar "intervalsS" property is not working in Mobile Phones

Tags: sapui5

I have a small issue in displaying of Calendar dates using [PlanningCalendarView](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.PlanningCalendarView) in Mobile Phones..

Property intervalS is not working in landscape. But it is working fine in Portrait mode. Below is the code im trying in View..

```
<PlanningCalendarView description="Days" intervalType="Day" key="Day" intervalsS="6" intervalsM="15" intervalsL="18"></PlanningCalendarView>
```

Portrait Mode..
[image]

Landscape Mode..
[image]

If you see the above screenshots in portrait mode it is showing 6 Dates, But in Landscape mode it is displaying 8 dates. But in my XML View i have configured `intervalsS` as 6.

Can some one please help me to configure 6 dates in Landscape mode?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

PlanningCalendarView parametr intervalS/M/L displays number of intervals depends on current screen pixels wide.

As You can read in documentation:

**intervalS**

- Defines the number of intervals that are displayed for a sap.m.PlanningCalendar that is less than 600 pixels wide.

**intervalsM**

- Defines the number of intervals that are displayed for a sap.m.PlanningCalendar that is between 600 and 1024 pixels wide.

Phone in the landscape mode will have ~800px so IntervalsM property is using during rendering component.

If You will change the property `intervalsM="15"` to `intervalsM="6"` it should correctly render 6 intervals on phone, but also it renders only 6 elements on a tablet.

Comment: Hello Majer,

Thank you for your response.

As you mentioned, My Mobile device is less that 600 pixels wide. But in landscape intervalsS parameter is not working.

Moreover, i mentioned intervalsM as "15", But im afraid why it is not considering intervalsM in landscape. It is displaying 8 dates in landscape which i didnt mentioned. If there is any issue in code or some other, Can you please help me to resolve..

Comment: Yes, but in landspace mode Your mobile device has more than 600px. Could You try to change intervalsM to "6" and test again?

Comment: i solved the issue by checking the device type in controller like this..
if (sap.ui.Device._getSystem().phone === true) {
                this.getView().byId("planningCalendarIntervals").setIntervalsM(7);

            }

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by myself with below tweak..

In the controller im just checking the device and im manually setting the calendar dates to 7

```
if (sap.ui.Device._getSystem().phone === true) {                 
   this.getView().byId("planningCalendarIntervals").setIntervalsM(7);       
}
```

View...

```
<PlanningCalendarView id="planningCalendarIntervals" description="Days" intervalType="Day" key="Day" intervalsS="7" intervalsM="15" intervalsL="18">`</PlanningCalendarView>
```